# SELECT * FROM OPENJSON -- Not getting expected values

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2019, open-json

I am getting 0 row when selecting from OPENJSON below.  I am expecting to get all 3 values "AA" for different as_of_date for CREDIT_RTG . I tried different select statements. I am running in SQL 2016.
Expected result should be similar to this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM0Ij.png)

Codes are posted below.  Thanks in advance

```
DECLARE @jsonVal varchar(max)
SET @jsonVal = '{
  "status": "OK",
  "code": 200,
  "trace_id": "3eea64f2a7917c11",
  "timestamp": "2023-05-31T14:36:02Z",
  "messages": [],
  "result": {
    "response_metadata": {
      "total_number_of_instruments": 1,
      "data_request_id_expiration_time": "2023-06-01T14:36:02+0000",
      "resolvedfactors": [
        "CREDIT_RTG",
        "ISSUER_NAME",
        "ISSUER_ISIN",
        "ISSUER_SEDOL",
        "ISSUERID"
      ]
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "requested_id": "IID000000002745031",
        "issuer_metadata": [
          {
            "ISSUERID": "IID000000002745031",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "ALPHABET INC.",
            "ISSUER_ISIN": "US02079K3059",
            "ISSUER_TICKER": "GOOGL",
            "as_of_date": "2019-09-01",
            "valid_until_date": "2019-09-14"
          },
          {
            "ISSUERID": "IID000000002745031",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "ALPHABET INC.",
            "ISSUER_ISIN": "US02079K1079",
            "ISSUER_TICKER": "GOOGL",
            "as_of_date": "2019-09-14",
            "valid_until_date": "2019-12-01"
          }
        ],
        "factors": [
          {
            "name": "CREDIT_RTG",
            "data_values": [
              {
                "value": "AA",
                "as_of_date": "2019-09-30",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.245957Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "AA",
                "as_of_date": "2019-10-31",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.245957Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "AA",
                "as_of_date": "2019-11-29",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.245957Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "ISSUER_NAME",
            "data_values": [
              {
                "value": "ALPHABET INC.",
                "as_of_date": "2019-09-30",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.246042Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "ALPHABET INC.",
                "as_of_date": "2019-10-31",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.246042Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "ALPHABET INC.",
                "as_of_date": "2019-11-29",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.246042Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "ISSUER_ISIN",
            "data_values": [
              {
                "value": "US02079K1079",
                "as_of_date": "2019-09-30",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.246006Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "US02079K1079",
                "as_of_date": "2019-10-31",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.246006Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "US02079K1079",
                "as_of_date": "2019-11-29",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.246006Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "ISSUER_SEDOL",
            "data_values": [
              {
                "value": "BYY88Y7",
                "as_of_date": "2019-09-30",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.246084Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "BYY88Y7",
                "as_of_date": "2019-10-31",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.246084Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "BYY88Y7",
                "as_of_date": "2019-11-29",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:02.246084Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "ISSUERID",
            "data_values": [
              {
                "value": "IID000000002745031",
                "as_of_date": "2019-09-30",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:00Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "IID000000002745031",
                "as_of_date": "2019-10-31",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:00Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              },
              {
                "value": "IID000000002745031",
                "as_of_date": "2019-11-29",
                "as_at_date": "2023-05-31T14:36:00Z",
                "reference_issuer_id": null,
                "reference_issuer_name": null
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}'


SELECT ISSUERID, CREDIT_RTG,  as_of_date  
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonVal,'$.result.data.factors')
with
(
    [ISSUERID] [varchar](20),
    [ISSUER_NAME] [varchar](50) ,
    CREDIT_RTG [varchar](20),
    as_of_date [varchar](20),
    value [varchar](20),

)
```

Comment: *" I am running in SQL 2019"* Why have you tagged SQL Server 2008 then? What version are you *really* using? `OPENJSON` isn't support in (the completely unsupported for the last 4 years) SQL Server 2008.

Comment: None of the elements in your object `factors` are called `ISSUERID`, `ISSUER_NAME`, or `CREDIT_RTG `, those are the values of the `name` element. What are you expected results here exactly? (Images of data isn't helpful).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;). All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are parsing the JSON appears to be unusual. It seems the `data_values` arrays are correlated across different `factors` objects.

So you need to first parse out the `factors` array into separate JSON sub-arrays, and pivot it up into columns. Then you can split out the `ISSUERID` array first, and correlate back to the others using `JSON_VALUE`. To get the array index for each row, you first need a separate call to `OPENJSON` with no schema, which returns `key, value` where the `key` is the index into the array.

Note that because both `$.result.data` and `factors` are arrays, you need separate `OPENJSON` calls to split them out. If there is only ever one `data` object then you can combine them with just `OPENJSON(@jsonval, '$.result.data[0].factors')`.

```sql
SELECT
  final.*
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonVal,'$.result.data')
  WITH
  (
    factors nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) j1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT pvt.*
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.factors)
      WITH
      (
        name varchar(50),
        data_values nvarchar(max) AS JSON
      ) j2
    PIVOT (MAX(data_values) FOR name IN
      (
        ISSUERID, ISSUER_NAME, CREDIT_RTG
      )
    ) pvt
) pvt
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      [ISSUERID] = issuerid.value,
      [ISSUER_NAME] = JSON_VALUE(pvt.ISSUER_NAME, '$[' + array.[key] + '].value'),
      CREDIT_RTG    = JSON_VALUE(pvt.CREDIT_RTG,  '$[' + array.[key] + '].value'),
      issuerid.as_of_date
    FROM OPENJSON(pvt.ISSUERID) array
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(array.value)
      WITH
      (
        value varchar(50),
        as_of_date date
      ) issuerid
) final;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/X8BY6eqe)

SQL Server 2016 does not allow dynamic JSON paths, so instead you need to do a `JOIN` between all the different arrays based on `key`

```sql
-- etc
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      [ISSUERID] = issuerid.value,
      [ISSUER_NAME] = JSON_VALUE(arrISSUER_NAME.value, '$.value'),
      CREDIT_RTG    = JSON_VALUE(arrCREDIT_RTG.value,  '$.value'),
      issuerid.as_of_date
    FROM OPENJSON(pvt.ISSUERID) arrISSUERID
    JOIN OPENJSON(pvt.ISSUER_NAME) arrISSUER_NAME ON arrISSUER_NAME.[key] = arrISSUERID.[key]
    JOIN OPENJSON(pvt.CREDIT_RTG ) arrCREDIT_RTG  ON arrCREDIT_RTG.[key]  = arrISSUERID.[key]
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(arrISSUERID.value)
      WITH
      (
        value varchar(50),
        as_of_date date
      ) issuerid
) final
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/SIPu-r_v)

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, I tried the code above in dbfiddle.uk and it works well with SQL 2019 and newer. It doesn't work with SQL 2016. I will try to troubleshoot but appreciate if you can share SQL 2016 codes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit simpler, albeit likely less performant openjson version:

```sql
select max(case when json_value(x.value, '$.name') = 'ISSUER_ISIN' then json_value(y.value, '$.value') end) AS ISSUER_ISIN
  , max(case when json_value(x.value, '$.name') = 'ISSUER_SEDOL' then json_value(y.value, '$.value') end) AS ISSUER_SEDOL
  , max(case when json_value(x.value, '$.name') = 'ISSUERID' then json_value(y.value, '$.value') end) AS ISSUERID
  , max(case when json_value(x.value, '$.name') = 'CREDIT_RTG' then json_value(y.value, '$.value') end) AS CREDIT_RTG
  , max(case when json_value(x.value, '$.name') = 'CREDIT_RTG' then json_value(y.value, '$.as_of_date') end) AS as_of_date
from openjson(@jsonVal, '$.result.data[0].factors') x
cross apply openjson(x.value,'$.data_values') y
group by y.[key]
```

It's a group by that fetches all the factors arrays and then pivots the fields depending on which array it operates on by using the array index as grouping field.

It's easy to add other fields by changing the json_values.